# mysqld problems

Tags: mysql

The following usage for mysqld doesn't seem right, and that time stamp! Anyone got any ideas why it is going crazy like that?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
25662 mysql     16   0  139m  30m 5256 S 88.9  1.7 312:17.23 mysqld
20200 apache    16   0  102m  14m 7548 S  5.0  0.8   0:01.42 httpd
```

I am a total newbie when it comes to mysql, Apache and Lighttpd configurations sure, but mysql totally clueless. Below is my my.conf. I am running on a machine with 2GB of memory and using InnoDB, connecting via PDO.

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Totally default to start from scratch and avoid errors, help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely look at your Processlist and see which query is so slow.

But from your "top" screenshout I would recommend the following changes in your my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
thread_cache_size = 64
table_cache = 64
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer_size = 256K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
tmp_table_size=16M
max_heap_table_size=16M
query_cache_size=64M
query_cache_type=1
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1000M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
```

You might need to do a bit of tweaking here and there next time you run into this problem, but these settings are quite good for the immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, use the *mysql* or *mysqladmin* command to access your server, and use it to run 'show processlist' to check which queries are currently running.

For example: `mysqladmin -u root -p processlist`. This will prompt you for the password of your mysql root user (not the same as your regular root account), and show you the currently running queries.

Also, a little tuning of your settings might be in order. I've found the [*mysqltuner.pl*](http://wiki.mysqltuner.com/MySQLTuner) script handy to give me pointers on where to start. Remember, it's just a start though. Spending a few hours to learn the basics of mysql performance tuning is a wise investment on such a heavy loaded server.

Comment: The gui tools can also give you a look at whats going on with the server.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd run a "show processlist" and see what kind of queries you've got running. It's obviously been sitting there chewing processor for some time.

Comment: You might find mytop of interest to see which queries are running the longest.

Comment: How do I do this? Simply "show processlist" in SSH doesn't work for me.

Comment: @James: Have a look at Martijn's comment - He's giving you the syntax for the command, assuming you have the mysql root password (not necessarily the same as the box's root password).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) during QA, and do some explains on the queries you capture. One of the most common things that I find web developers do to my databases is sort without an index. Another is to put a bunch of pointless indexes on a table that gets frequent insert/update/deletes. Adding indexes that never get used just hurts your write performance. There is a lot of info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html), but it is worth applying.

I would also suggest installing and monitoring [sar/sysstat](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/52570).